# C error : Expected expression before THROTTLE_MAP_Handle a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, structure, sensors, throttling

I have been working on calibration of throttle sensor and i have written the respective c headers and programs that checks the function of a throttle sensor but i end up with the below error. I have placed my code in which the error is being thrown

```
#include "Throttle_Map.h"
#include "main.h"
int main()
{
float inputValue;
for (inputValue=0; inputValue<=5 ; inputValue=inputValue+0.5)
{
THROTTLE_MAP_Equation(THROTTLE_MAP_Handle handle, const float inputValue);
}
}
```

The below are the error message:

```
14  32  D:\CIC\Codes\main.c [Error] expected expression before 'THROTTLE_MAP_Handle'
14  9   D:\CIC\Codes\main.c [Error] too few arguments to function 'THROTTLE_MAP_Equation'
```

Comment: Sure. I will add the header file content.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I suggest you consult your C text book and look at the part about calling functions. You mixed syntax for declaring a function with syntax for calling a function.

Answer (score 0):

Do not include parameter types when you are calling a function:

```
THROTTLE_MAP_Equation(handle, inputValue);
```

Comment: I am also missing the definition of 'handle'. And where is the typedef THROTTLE_MAP_Handle?

Comment: the typedef of it is present in the one more header file, the content of which i will place it below